# How do I wrap a css knockout binding with custom binding?

Tags: knockout.js, bindinghandlers

I am trying to create a custom binding which will encapsulate a series of css bindings. Specifically, instead of:

```
data-bind="css: { success: PickInventoryViewModel.ajaxSuccess, fail: PickInventoryViewModel.ajaxFailure, working: PickInventoryViewModel.ajaxWorking }"
```

I want this:

```
data-bind="ajaxStatus: PickInventoryViewModel"
```

The `ajaxStatus` binding would be a custom binding which would initiate the appropriate css bindings rather than having this implementation detail sprinkled throughout my app. However, the `css` bindingHandler doesn't have an init function so I'm not entirely sure how to go about making this work.

I suppose I could subscribe to each of the observables and call `ko.bindingHandlers['css'].update` when the observed value is `true`. Another possible option I've considered is to inject the css binding to the html element and rebind the node (I think that's the essence of `applyBindingsToNode` as exemplified [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvc2b/2/).

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks,
Vinney

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from your custom binding init function do

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: { /* stuff */ } });
```

Comment: Perfect! Gotta love when the answer to your *problem* can be expressed in a 2-line response ;)